Using DateOnly with Entity Framework Core and MySql
I'm using .Net 8 and EF Core 8 with MySQL and want to use the DateOnly type. Whenever I try to read data from the database I get the following error:

'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.DateOnly'.'
at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.g__ProcessCurrentElementRow|23_0[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](<>c__DisplayClass23_02& ) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](Int32 collectionId, QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, SingleQueryResultCoordinator resultCoordinator, Func3 parentIdentifier, Func3 outerIdentifier, Func3 selfIdentifier, IReadOnlyList1 parentIdentifierValueComparers, IReadOnlyList1 outerIdentifierValueComparers, IReadOnlyList1 selfIdentifierValueComparers, Func5 innerShaper, INavigationBase inverseNavigation, Action2 fixup, Boolean trackingQuery) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)

The problem seems to be that EF Core uses MySqlDataReader.GetValue which appears to not support DateOnly as a default as adressed here: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1451.
I was wondering if I'm missing something or if there is a workaround for this, since there doesn't seem to be any activity lately.

Have you tried the workarounds in the issue? MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<DateOnly> or MySqlDataReader.GetDateOnly?

The code calling MySqlDataReader.GetValue is part of the entity framework so unfortunatly I can't change how the value is read.

The code seems to be calling MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>, not MySqlDataReader.GetValue. If you were using MySqlConnector (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) this would work, but you're using MySql.Data, so it won't. Oracle's EF implementation is very poor, so many other answers on this site will recommend switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql instead. I would echo that recommendation.

@BradleyGrainger: Thanks for pointing this out. The Pomelo MySQL implementation looks promising to me. I'll take a closer look to this

Instead of cast or implicit conversion, I expect you'll need to purposefully use the DateOnly.FromDateTime() method.
